# What is the shortest way to make a lot of plots with different axes for the same data?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make my code readable and nice.

My functions are

```
W[L_, r_] := 1 + 3 L + 2 L^2 - 6 r*L - 6 L (r*L) + 6 (r*L)^2;
T[L_, r_, d_, koff_, u_, W_] := ((u/d^2)* W[L, r]+6 u (L - 1)) + koff (u/d^2) W[L, r]
```

Here I import my data

```
d0 = Import["t0_vs_L_koff0_u3_kon" <> # <> ".dat"] & /@ {"01", "1", "10", "102"};
d3 = Import["t0_vs_L_koff3_u3_kon" <> # <> ".dat"] & /@ {"01", "1", "10", "102"};
d6 = Import["t0_vs_L_koff6_u3_kon" <> # <> ".dat"] & /@ {"01", "1", "10", "102"};
```

After that I give a vector of parameters which I want to use

```
konVals = {0.1, 1, 10, 100};
```

And after that I make two plots for

> koff=1

in usual axes

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, 1, 10^3], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 1000}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, 
      PlotLabel -> "T vs L, koff=1", 
      PlotLegends -> konVals, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}], 
     ListPlot[d0, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}]]
```

and log-log axes

```
Show[LogPlot[
      Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, 1, 10^3], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 1000}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, 
      PlotLabel -> "T) vs L, koff=1", 
      PlotLegends -> konVals], ListLogPlot[d0], 
     Style -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}]
```

2 plots for

> koff=10^3

in usual axes

```
Show[Plot[
          Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, 10^3, 10^3, W], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 
           1000}, AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, 
          PlotLabel -> "T vs L, koff=10^3", 
          PlotLegends -> konVals], ListPlot[d3], 
         Style -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}]
```

and log-log

```
 Show[LogPlot[
      Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, 10^3, 10^3, W], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 
       1000}, AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, 
      PlotLabel -> "T vs L, koff=10^3", 
      PlotLegends -> konVals], ListLogPlot[d3], 
     Style -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}]
```

And for

> koff=10^6

do the same thing

```
Show[Plot[
          Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, 10^6, 10^3, W], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 
           1000}, AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, 
          PlotLabel -> "T vs L, koff=10^6", 
          PlotLegends -> konVals], ListPlot[d6], 
         Style -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}]
```

and in log-log scale

```
    Show[LogPlot[
      Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, 10^6, 10^3, W], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 
       1000}, AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, 
      PlotLabel -> "T vs L, koff=10^6", 
      PlotLegends -> konVals], ListLogPlot[d6], 
     Style -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}]
```

Could you please suggest the shortest and easiest way to do that? Can I download all data in one string? Can I than use this to plot everything much faster?

Comment: try this `Grid[Table[{Plot[ # , {x, 2, 100}], LogPlot[ # , {x, 2, 100}]} &@ (x^
     k) , {k, 3}]]` for some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following functions:

```
normplot[data_, koff_String] := Show[
  Plot[
   Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, 1, 10^3], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 1000},
   AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, PlotLabel -> "T vs L, koff = " <> koff, 
   PlotLegends -> konVals, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}
   ],
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}],
  ImageSize -> Large
]

logplot[data_, koff_String] := Show[
  LogPlot[
   Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, 1, 10^3], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 1000},
   AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, PlotLabel -> "T) vs L, koff" <> koff, 
   PlotLegends -> konVals
   ],
  ListLogPlot[data],
  Style -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange},
  ImageSize -> Large
]
```

You should then be able to generate all your plots by evaluating:

```
MapThread[{normplot[#1, #2], logplot[#1, #2]} &, {{d0, d3, d6}, {"1", "10^3", "10^6"}}]
```

Comment: It looks like plots I generate didn't have different values of `koff` (function just take one value of `koff` for all plots). Could you please help me and explain why it is so?

Comment: I fixed the problem. The correct code `normplot[data_, koff_] := 
  Show[Plot[
    Evaluate@Table[T[L, 0.5, n, koff, 10^3], {n, konVals}], {L, 2, 
     1000}, AxesLabel -> {"L", "T"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "T vs L, koff = " <> ToString[koff], 
    PlotLegends -> konVals, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}], 
   ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}], 
   ImageSize -> Medium];`